# Razor Pages - Passing abstract class to Html.Partial expecting an interface throws an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have:

1. An interface with 2 generics
2. An abstract class that implements the interface and `PageModel`
3. A class for the razor page that implements the abstract class
4. A partial that expects the interface

When I try `@await Html.PartialAsync("_InterfacePartial", Model)` it throws the below

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'IndexPageModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'IPage`2[System.Object,IRow]'.
>
> *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object value)*

IPage.cs

```cs
public interface IPage<T, T2>
    where T : class
    where T2 : IRow
{
    // STRIPPED FOR BREVITY

    IQueryable<T> GetQueryable();

    IEnumerable<T2> GetResults(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

AbstractPage.cs

```cs
public abstract class AbstractPage<T, T2> : PageModel, IPage<T, T2>
    where T : class
    where T2 : IRow
{
    // STRIPPED FOR BREVITY

    public abstract IQueryable<T> GetQueryable();

    public IEnumerable<T2> GetResults(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var fields = ... // Edit after answer => `var fields = GetTableFields();` returns Func<T, T2>

        return GetQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList().Select(fields);
    }
}
```

IndexPageModel.cshtml.cs

```cs
public class IndexPageModel : AbstractPage<Thing, ThingRow>
{
    public override IQueryable<Order> GetQueryable()
    {
        return MyDbContext.Things.Include(x => x.AnExtraThing);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I just a mad man trying to do the impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to some concepts: ***assignment compatibility***, ***covariance*** and ***contravariance***.

Covariance preserves assignment compatibility whereas contravariance reverses assign compatibility. You can learn more about that here [Covariance & Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

So in this case, your page's declared model type is an interface with generic arguments but to support accepting (assignment) value from some instance with arguments of more derived (more concrete) type, you need to support ***covariance*** for that interface type by using the keyword `out`, as follows:

```
public interface IPage<out T, out T2>
where T : class
where T2 : IRow
{ ... }
```

That luckily matches with the return types used in the methods of your interface. So you can see that both `T` and `T2` are returned types. If one of them is an argument type, you will be stuck and should consider about your design of the interface. Here is an example of the interface that **cannot** be declared to support covariance:

```
//has compile-time error
public interface IPage<out T, out T2>
where T : class
where T2 : IRow
{    
   IQueryable<T> GetQueryable();
   IEnumerable<T2> GetResults(Func<T, bool> predicate);
   //just an example, this will violate the covariance rule
   //because T2 cannot be used as an input (argument) type once declared with out
   int ComputeSomeThing(T2 row);
}
```

So behind the scene, your page model will be assigned to `IndexPageModel` OK like this (for demonstrative purpose only, not exactly what happens):

```
IPage<object,IRow> model = new IndexPageModel(...);
```

**UPDATE**:

About a more complicated scenario in which you have the generic type `T` not used directly as argument type or return type but instead in another generic type that also has variant generic types, such as `Func`. Here is an example of such complicated example:

```
public interface IComplicatedVariant<in T, out TResult> {
     Func<T, TResult> GetFunc();
     void SetFunc(Func<TResult, T> f);
}
```

As you can see, the return type `Func<T, TResult>` accepts generic argument types `T` (contravariant) and `TResult` (covariant) of the same variance (like cascading down from the type `IComplicatedVariant`). However when using an argument type of `Func`, we need to reverse the variance of generic types passed in `Func`. So instead of `Func<T,TResult>` (which is invalid and will have design-time error), we can only pass `Func<TResult,T>` or in short, `T` cannot be used in `Func<T, ...>` and `TResult` cannot be used in `Func<...,TResult>`.

The second method `SetFunc` is harder to be explained without concrete example. The generic arguments' variance seems to be ***reversed***.
Suppose `T` can be used in `Func<T,...>` for `SetFunc`, we have:

```
//T1, T2 here are concrete types, not generic argument types
var a = new ComplicatedVariant<object,T2>();
IComplicatedVariant<T1, T2> o = a;
Func<T1,T2> f = ...;
//OK
o.SetFunc(f);
//BUT this is not OK
a.SetFunc(f);
```

The above example is an assumption to show that what will become wrong without reversing the variance (as mentioned above). You can see that `a.SetFunc` requires a `Func<object,T2>` but the passed-in argument is a `Func<T1,T2>`. The first argument type in `Func<,>` is ***contravariant*** (declared with `in T`), so it ***reverses the assignment compatibility***, which means the first generic argument type ***on the left*** side should be ***equal or more derived*** than the type ***on the right*** side. So we cannot assign the func like this (pseudo-code):

```
//cannot be set like this, the reverse is however OK
Func<object,T2> = Func<T1,T2>
```

The argument cannot be accepted (in the call `a.SetFunc`) meaning it violates the variance designed for the interface `IComplicatedVariant`. So our original assumption is invalid. As I said, we use a concrete example to show an invalid case (by assumption). It's fairly complicated but luckily that we have the design-time compiler which can help report the error right at the design time. If you're not sure, you can just try it out and see if it works right at the design time.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I did have a couple of methods that had `Func<T, ...` but I moved them to the abstract class.

Comment: @glenn223 what do you mean? is this still not working? if you have real code that's not posted (which somehow makes this solution not applicable), then please update your question with that code, I may help then.

Comment: Sorry, yes it does work. Mistakenly removed the answer tick ‍♂️

Comment: My problem was a few methods in the interface returning `Func<T, T2>` (e.g. `Func<T, T2> GetTableFields();`). These were obviously not going to work so I moved them to the abstract class. However, if I misunderstood and you can have this function in the interface then I'll happily edit my question

Comment: @glenn223 I think the methods returning `Func<...,T2>` works but `Func<T,T2>` does not because the `T` is `out` and `Func\`2` is declared as `Func<in T,out TResult>`. So `out T` cannot be put in `in T` when methods returning a `Func\`2`. However it's OK to have arguments of `Func<T,...>` (as in your code we have `Func<T, bool>`). Note that the variance is reversed when used in generic type (for arguments & return types) with variance like `Func<T,TResult>`. You can try it out yourself easily. We have no work-around for this, just adapt your design accordingly.